Efficient and Secure Access to Images in Azure Blob Storage for a List of Products
I’m developing an application where I have a list of products, each with an associated image stored in Azure Blob Storage, and I need a secure and efficient way to provide access to these images on the frontend.
Initially, I considered saving public urls of the images in the database during upload. However, enabling public access to the storage container isn’t secure, so I discarded this option.
The alternative I’m considering is using SAS urls for secure access. However, since these urls have an expiration time, I would need to regenerate them every time I fetch the list of products from the backend. This would require looping through all products and creating a new SAS url for each image dynamically.
This raises a few concerns:
•   Will generating SAS URLs for multiple images on each request significantly impact performance, especially when the product list is large?
•   Does frequent SAS URL generation result in increased costs, especially with a large number of requests?
•   What’s the most efficient and secure way to manage this process?
My goal is to keep the images private, ensure efficient access, and avoid unnecessary costs.

If the images should be public accessible then I don't see what is unsafe to set up a dedicated storage account for them with public read access to the container holding them. What do I miss? Is the whole product catalog behind a login or something?

I agree with @PeterBons, catalog images should generally be publicly available. You could always obfuscate the image names so someone couldn't figure out the image url for a given product without accessing your frontend by simply using GUIDs as the image names/paths.


Will generating SAS URLs for multiple images on each request
significantly impact performance, especially when the product list is
large?

I have not heard that this would be an issue, because SAS generation is done by your server. However, this is something that you should be able to test somewhat easily if your server is affected by this.

Does frequent SAS URL generation result in increased costs, especially
with a large number of requests?

Storage cost isn't affected by this.

What’s the most efficient and secure way to manage this process?
Couple of points:


SAS tokens should short lived.
Only read access

However, I would also consider using Microsoft Entra ID authentication if that is possible in your case. Also, one option is to pipe the images trough the App Service (or whatever you are using here) and handle the authentication and authorization there.
Sources
